# Kotlin With If Not Null

Tags: null, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

What would be the most concise way of using `with` iff a `var` is not `null`?

The best I could come up with is:

```
arg?.let { with(it) {

}}
```

Comment: `it` is already not null because you are using `arg?.let {} `

Comment: Yes, but the point is that I want to use `with` with a non null value. I want to use `with` for its scoping.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the Kotlin extension functions [`apply()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) or [`run()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) depending on whether you want it to be **fluent** (*returning `this` at end*) or **transforming** (*returning a new value at end*):

Usage for `apply`:

```
something?.apply {
    // this is now the non-null arg
}
```

And fluent example:

```
user?.apply {
   name = "Fred"
   age = 31
}?.updateUserInfo()
```

Transforming example using `run`:

```
val companyName = user?.run {
   saveUser()
   fetchUserCompany()
}?.name ?: "unknown company"
```

---

Alternatively if you don't like that naming and really want a function called `with()` **you can easily create your own reusable function**:

```
// returning the same value fluently
inline fun <T: Any> T.with(func: T.() -> Unit): T = this.apply(func)
// or returning a new value
inline fun <T: Any, R: Any> T.with(func: T.() -> R): R = this.func()
```

Example usage:

```
something?.with {
    // this is now the non-null arg
}
```

If you want the null check embedded in the function, maybe a `withNotNull` function?

```
// version returning `this` or `null` fluently
inline fun <T: Any> T?.withNotNull(func: T.() -> Unit): T? = 
    this?.apply(func)
// version returning new value or `null`
inline fun <T: Any, R: Any> T?.withNotNull(thenDo: T.() -> R?): R? =
    this?.thenDo()
```

Example usage:

```
something.withNotNull {
    // this is now the non-null arg
}
```

---

See also:

- Related [functions on `Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/index.html)
- Kotlin [top-level functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/index.html#functions)
- [Kotlin StdLib API Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html)

Comment: Awesome! I find myself loving Kotlin more and more every time I see something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the alternative to that would be to use:

```
arg?.run {

}
```